# why .change() isn't executing after value change of input by jquery queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$("body").on('change' , '.pp',function(){
    var price = $(".pp").val();
    price = parseInt(price);
    var quantity = $(".ss").val();
    quantity = parseInt(quantity);
    var amount = (price*quantity);
    $(".rr").val(amount);
    });
/* so from the about what i think is first value was 0 then it is changed to value assigned by the above jquery, until this its working fine but problem arises below, another jquery where severals amount(.pricing) are added and value is assigned to ("#totalAmount") */
    
     $(document).on('change', '.pricing', function() {
        var total=0;
        $(".pricing").each(function(){
            quantity = parseInt($(this).val());
            if (!isNaN(quantity)) {
                total += quantity;
            }
        });
        $("#totalAmount").val(total);
    });
/*  */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Lets suppose i have an input field which has value=0 as given in html -->
<input type="text" value="0" class="rr pricing" name="amount">

    <input type="text" class="ss" name="price">
    <input type="text" class="pp" name="qty">
<!-- Jquery used to set value of input[name="amount"] from these two inputs -->
```

its not executing unless i manually click on .pricing input field and change it manually, shouldn't my above jquery calculation changes to value of it hence theoretically it should execute, or am i doing something wrong.

Comment: no,it will not execute if you change the value using code

Comment: then how can i achieve the below jquery because i want my code to change value ?

Comment: that is a little complicated,you wanna know?

Comment: yes @xianshenglu

Comment: The `$("body").on('change', '.pp', function(){ ... })` in its current form will assign the result of (_first_ `.pp` element times the _first_ `.ss` element) to _all_ `.rr` elements. Hence `#totalAmount` will always be: ((_first_ `.pp` element times the _first_ `.ss` element) times the number of `.pricing` elements)

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+onchange+not+triggered+when+value+changed+by+script

Comment: @AdernNerk learn something about vue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `change` event is only triggered automatically when the user changes something, not when it's changed by Javascript. You need to trigger it yourself.

Change the line:

```
$(".rr").val(amount);
```

to:

```
$(".rr").val(amount).trigger("change");
```

Comment: can you elaborate more ?

Comment: That only matters for binding event handlers, it has nothing to do with triggering events.

Answer (score 1):

You need to trigger it yourself. For that you can use following code,

```
$("body").on('change' , '.pp',function(){
var price = $(".pp").val();
price = parseInt(price);
var quantity = $(".ss").val();
quantity = parseInt(quantity);
var amount = (price*quantity);
$(".rr").val(amount);
$(".pricing").trigger('change');
// or $(".pricing").change();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

i give you a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xianshenglu/fsa3f6kd/),but not solving your present problem;

pay attention the js code in the end,once you change the value of data-type,the className auto change and the background-color auto change.

the core code is Object.defineProperty,and the related framework is Vue.

```js
let bonusDiv = document.getElementById('bonusDiv');

    Object.defineProperty(bonusDiv, 'data-type', {
        configurable: true,
        set: function(value) {
            switch (value) {
                case 'x1':
                    this.className = 'red';
                    break;
                case 'x2':
                    this.className = 'blue';
                    break;
                case 'x3':
                    this.className = 'purple';
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
    bonusDiv['data-type']='x1';
    console.log('you set bonusDiv data-type,so bonusDiv className autoChange to=>'+bonusDiv.className);
    bonusDiv['data-type']='x2';
    console.log('you set bonusDiv data-type,so bonusDiv className autoChange to=>'+bonusDiv.className);
    bonusDiv['data-type']='x3';
    console.log('you set bonusDiv data-type,so bonusDiv className autoChange to=>'+bonusDiv.className);
```

```css
.red {
  background-color:red;
}
.blue {
  background-color:blue;
}
.purple {
  background-color:purple;
}
```

```html
<div id="bonusDiv" >bonusDiv</div>
```